# Excel data validation including numeric and text criteria

Tags: excel, validation

I am using Excel validation to restrict the entry values based upon adjacent cells but also need to restrict the entry to numeric values only.

Ideally, i would like to use the custom formula (=(SUM(I15:K15)<1, for example) but combine this with the standard Decimal validation option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom data validation formula can be for example

```
= AND( IsNumber( A1 ) , A1 >= 1 , A1 <= 2 , SUM( I15:K15 ) < 1 )
```

but it will not be validated when any other cells are changed ( `I15:K15` ), so you can also add conditional formatting to the range with a formula like

```
= SUM( I15:K15 ) >= 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Slai, this is exactly what I was looking for